# A reset Button on canvas

Tags: android

I need to make a Button that cleans my canvas and also a safe button.
I would like that the Activity stays like it is . And just Path what was drawn would be deleted.Thank you so much for any help. My Code:

```
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.graphics.Canvas;
  import android.graphics.Color;
  import android.graphics.Paint;
  import android.graphics.Path;
  import android.util.AttributeSet;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
  import android.view.View;



public class TouchEventDraw extends View {
//Variable

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path = new Path();

//Konstruktor
public TouchEventDraw(Context context, AttributeSet attrset) {
    super(context, attrset);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

}


/**
 * The most important step in drawing a custom view is to override the        
* @param canvas object that the view can use to draw itself. */
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(path.isEmpty())
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    else
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}

 /**
  * Method to handle touch screen motion events.
  * @param event The motion event
  * @return True if the event was handled, false otherwise.*/
  @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float xPos = event.getX();
    float yPos = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(xPos,yPos);
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            path.lineTo(xPos,yPos);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
 }
 public void clear(){
    path = new Path();
    invalidate();
 }

}
```

And my Activity with Buttons:

```
   import android.graphics.Canvas;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.Button;

 public class DrawingScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
 Button btn;
  TouchEventDraw ted;
 Canvas canva;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 ted=new TouchEventDraw(this,null);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawing_screen);
    btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

}
private final View.OnClickListener onClickListener=new    View.OnClickListener() {     
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
 ted.clear();
ted.invalidate();
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a method to your `TouchEventDraw` class, and call the following in it

```
canva.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Then on your button click, call the method you created.

You should be able to implement the solution with the information I supplied.

I think there are more fatal issues through your code though, as I see the following:

1. The view is never being put on screen.
2. You extend View, rather than SurfaceView.

Another way, you should be able to create a method, and instead set `path` empty

```
public void clear(){
   path = new Path();
}
```

then change your draw to

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(path.isEmpty())
       canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    else 
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}
```

and call `View.invalidate();`

Comment: you mean like this:                                                                            public void clear(Canvas canva){
        canva.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

Comment: @Veni Yes. However, you do not have the canvas parameter to pass in. And i think this is due to using a `View`, rather than `SurfaceView`. So you may need to rework your code. I have another idea, using paths. let me edit my answer.

Comment: @Veni If you have the canvas it will. Fair enough. Will add alternative anyway.

Comment: I have updated Code with all your suggestions, but it still doesn't work correct

Comment: @Veni code looks better now, so unsure why it wouldnt work. try `postInvalidate` instead of `invalidate`. Also add Logging, to see which parts are being called.